# com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.R does not exist

Tags: android, google-cast

I try to intergrate [Github - CastCompanionLibrary-android is a library project](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) into my project, but when build i face this error:

```
    D:\Android\MediaPlayer\app\src\main\java\com\google\android\libraries\cast\companionlibrary\cast\VideoCastManager.java:40: 
    error: cannot find symbol
    import com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.R;                                                  ^
```

I google so much but not found solution yet, I use **Android studio**.
Please help me how to resolve this solution

This is code error, in file `VideoCastManager.java`

```java
import com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaInfo;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaMetadata;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaTrack;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.RemoteMediaPlayer;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.common.images.WebImage;
import com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.R;
```

I have build successfull with `gradlew build --stacktrace`

```
D:\Android\CastCompanionLibrary-android-master>gradlew build --stacktrace
:compileLint
:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:preBuild
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:preDebugTestBuild
:preReleaseBuild
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72210Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72210Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42210Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase700Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast700Library
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:compileDebugRenderscript
:generateDebugBuildConfig
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:generateDebugResValues
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:compileDebugJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:extractDebugAnnotations
:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:packageDebugJar
:compileDebugNdk
:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:packageDebugResources
:bundleDebug
:assembleDebug
:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeReleaseAssets
:generateReleaseResValues
:generateReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
:processReleaseManifest
:processReleaseResources
:generateReleaseSources
:compileReleaseJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:extractReleaseAnnotations
:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:packageReleaseJar
:compileReleaseNdk
:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:packageReleaseResources
:bundleRelease
:assembleRelease
:assemble
:lint
Ran lint on variant debug: 185 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 185 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:/D:/Android/CastCompanionLibrary-android-master/build/
outputs/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to D:\Android\CastCompanionLibrary-android-master\build\outputs
\lint-results.xml
:check
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3 mins 17.086 secs
D:\Android\CastCompanionLibrary-android-master>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you can build CastCompanionLibrary; clone that to your local filesystem and go into its root directory and try to build with gradle: "./gradlew build". Then see if it successfully builds or not. Once that step is done, follow the same steps as described in CastVideos project to use CCL in your own project.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue.

`R.java is the dynamically generated class, created during build process to dynamically identify all assets (from strings to android widgets to layouts), for usage in java classes in Android app. Note this R.java is Android specific (though you may be able to duplicate it for other platforms, its very convenient) so it doesnt have much to do with Java language constructs. Take a look here, for more details.`

So when copy code in my project, I need change to my package in manifest instead keep old package. example:
change

```
import com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.R;
```

to

```
import com.example.android.uamp.R;
```